# Can WebDriverWait be used on an element that has already been defined?

Tags: c#, selenium, webdriverwait

I'm building an automation framework which uses the Page Object Model (POM) and have a class file called HomePage.

I have already declared the element using :

```
[FindsBy(How = How.Id, Using = "TextField1")]
private IWebElement FirstTextField{ get; set; }
```

I have declared my WebDriverWait as below:

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver,TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30));
```

I have a method in the HomePage.cs called Validate() and within this I want to use 
WebDriverWait as follows:

```
wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementIsVisible(FirstTextField))
```

How can I use the WebDriverWait this way, rather than having to use the By locator:

```
wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementIsVisible(By.Id("TextField1")));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ExpectedConditions.ElementIsVisible()` doesn't have overload for `IWebElement` in C# [ExpectedConditions](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/dotnet/html/T_OpenQA_Selenium_Support_UI_ExpectedConditions.htm). You could use custom implementation

```
public static Func<IWebDriver, IWebElement> ElementIsVisible(IWebElement element)
{
    return (driver) =>
        {
            try
            {
                return return element.Displayed ? element : null;
            }
            catch (StaleElementReferenceException)
            {
                return null;
            }
        };
}
```

Uses:

```
wait.Until(ElementIsVisible(FirstTextField));
```

Comment: Thanks Guy - I've got the code in the HomePage class and so far no build errors. Say I wanted to put it in a seperate class called Element_Extensions which is located in an Extensions folder, how would I go about calling it from within my HomePage class. I have already declared using `projName.Extensions;`

Comment: I've managed to sort it... I copied the code you provided above into my Element_Extensions class and then used `Element_Extensions.ElementIsVisible(FirstTextField);` , ran my test and got a pass!

Comment: @SGold Great to hear.

Comment: Apologies I meant `wait.Until(Element_Extensions.ElementIsVisible(FirstTextField));`

Comment: You will probably also want to catch `NoSuchElementException`s as well.  There will be times when it hasn't rendered so you cannot work out if it is visible or not.